# Using pubsub with golang: ocgrpc.NewClientStatsHandler

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am following this tutorial to publish a topic to Pub/Sub from a golang project and here's the code I have for that project at the moment:

```
package main

import "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

All it does is simply imports the pubsub but when I run `go get` I get this error: `undefined: ocgrpc.NewClientStatsHandler`

```
C:\Users\iha001\Dev\golang-projects\src\github.com\naguibihab\golang-playarea\src\gcloud>go get
# cloud.google.com/go/pubsub
..\..\..\..\..\cloud.google.com\go\pubsub\go18.go:34:51: undefined: ocgrpc.NewClientStatsHandler
```

Is there anything else I need to install to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been an issue on the repo:

> @naguibihab This is NOT a windows issue. This commit fixes the problem
>   be072a5. Short explanation: breaking changes where pushed on a minor
>   release of a google pubsub dependency:
>   census-instrumentation/opencensus-go@ac82455, method
>   NewClientStatsHandler was deleted. (They don't claim anywhere they
>   comply with semver).

Here's the fix mentioned in that comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/commit/be072a5d1d73144ae0ce1071e9bd43d1ad221581

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on mac, using "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub" version 0.19.0. The fix for me was bumping the version down to 0.18.0.

Comment: Check my answer and see if that fixes your issue as well

Comment: Looks like that fix is only on master currently, and I'm not seeing a patch release (unless I'm missing it?). I try to keep my dependencies pinned to releases rather than master, so the fix is still bumping down to 0.18.0 for me. Good to know there's already a fix for the next release though!

Comment: Maybe fork and cherry pick that commit until it comes in a patch release